# JavaScript: indexOf vs. Match when Searching Strings?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, client

Are there any discernable performance differences between using

```
str.indexOf("src")
```

and

```
str.match(/src/)
```

I personally prefer `match` (and regexp) but colleagues seem to go the other way. We were wondering if it mattered ...?

EDIT:

I should have said at the outset that this is for functions that will be doing partial plain-string matching (to pick up identifiers in class attributes for JQuery) rather than full regexp searches with wildcards etc.

```
class='redBorder DisablesGuiClass-2345-2d73-83hf-8293'
```

So it's the difference between:

```
string.indexOf('DisablesGuiClass-');
```

and

```
string.match(/DisablesGuiClass-/)
```

Comment: I think `str.indexOf("xyz")` should be compared with `/xyz/.test(str)`

Comment: here a benchmark, which compares indexOf, regex and match http://jsben.ch/#/r9hBp

Comment: Actually `String.prototype.indexOf` is more comparable to `String.prototype.search` because both will return the start index of the match. The boolean expression `'foo'.indexOf('bar') !== -1` is better comparable to `/bar/.test('foo')` because both result in a bool value. That said, for simple expressions without groups and anchors the performance should be comparable. `str.match` is wasting doing too much because it returns all the matches and I would advise against using it for comparisons.That said, if you don't have a performance problem chose the one that is more readable.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

RegExp is indeed slower than indexOf (you can see it [here](http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof)), though normally this shouldn't be an issue. With RegExp, you also have to make sure the string is properly escaped, which is an extra thing to think about.

Both of those issues aside, if two tools do exactly what you need them to, why not choose the simpler one?

Comment: Makes sense to me, henceforth we'll be running with `indexOf` unless additional RegExp functionality is required. Many thanks!

PS. That configurable testpage you linked to in your response is cool - is it a publicly available thing or something of your own devising?

Comment: @5arx, jsperf, like jsfiddle, is an indispensable tool for quickly testing ideas out. It's a public site, just go to jsperf.com and create your own tests.

Comment: According to this jsperf test it simple not true that indexOf is always fast: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5296314/981933

Comment: The test to which you refer might be accurate, or might not -- it certainly got the RegExp wrong, which does not inspire confidence. `'[\\?|&]'` should be `[?&]` to match either `?` or `&` -- no need for an `|` operator, nor escaping the `?`.

Comment: Just to add historical color: As of the date of this comment, on my machine (2017 MBP w/ Chrome 56.0.2924 on Mac OS X 10.12.3), the test linked to in the answer says that the `indexOf` is 12% slower than the regex match. So, with many things, the right answer is probably: It depends.

Comment: I don't think this is a complete result since the OP was talking about matching strings, and in a use-case scenario. Changing the test to search for two different strings in the same OR conditional, match/regexp methods can be incredibly slow compared to indexOf (90%). If you find yourself in a situation where you can make the search pattern more terse in situations like the test (pattern in a single regexp), match is almost more than certainly the better choice since you are also reducing the amount of handler code as well.

Comment: The jsperf also recreated the regex in each test case, which slowed down non-regex cases significantly.  Check https://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof/52 and see that the regex is ~96% slower in a more real-world case.

Comment: Definitely seems to depend, and may have changed since the last comments were made... This benchmark test shows regex (especially pre-compiled) is faster: http://jsben.ch/Jw5yT

Answer (score 21):

Here all possible ways (relatively) to search for string

// 1. includes (introduced in ES6)

```
var string = "string to search for substring",
    substring = "sea";
string.includes(substring);
```

// 2. string.indexOf

```
var string = "string to search for substring",
    substring = "sea";
string.indexOf(substring) !== -1;
```

// 3. RegExp: test

```
var string = "string to search for substring",
    expr = /sea/;  // no quotes here
expr.test(string);
```

// 4. string.match

```
var string = "string to search for substring",
    expr = "/sea/";
string.match(expr);
```

//5. string.search

```
var string = "string to search for substring",
    expr = "/sea/";
string.search(expr);
```

Here a src: https://koukia.ca/top-6-ways-to-search-for-a-string-in-javascript-and-performance-benchmarks-ce3e9b81ad31

Benchmarks seem to be twisted specially for es6 includes , read the comments.

## In resume:

if you don't need the matches. 
=> Either you need regex and so use **test**. Otherwise es6 **includes** or **indexOf**.  Still **test** vs **indexOf** are close.

### And for includes vs indexOf:

They seem to be the same : https://jsperf.com/array-indexof-vs-includes/4  (if it was different it would be wierd, they mostly perform the same except for the differences that they expose [check this](https://www.codementor.io/adroitcoder/includes-vs-indexof-in-javascript-ivxhatb3y))

And for my own benchmark test. here it is http://jsben.ch/fFnA0
You can test it (it's browser dependent) [test multiple time]
here how it performed (multiple run indexOf and includes one beat the other, and they are close). So they are the same. [here using the same test platform as the article above].

[image]
[image]

And here for the a long text version (8 times longer)
http://jsben.ch/wSBA2

[image]

Tested  both chrome and firefox, same thing.

Notice jsben.ch doesn't handle memory overflow (or there limits correctly. It doesn't show any message) so result can get wrong if you add more then 8 text duplication (8 work well). But the conclusion is for very big text all three perform the same way. Otherwise for short indexOf and includes are the same and test a little bit slower. or Can be the same as it seemed in chrome (firefox 60 it is slower).

Notice with jsben.ch: don't freak out if you get inconsistant result. Try different time and see if it's consistent or not. Change browser, sometimes they just run totally wrong. Bug or bad handling of memory. Or something.

ex:

[image]

Here too my benchmark on jsperf (better details, and handle graphs for multiple browsers)

(top is chrome)

**normal text**
https://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-includes-vs-test-2019 
**resume:** includes and indexOf have same perofrmance. test slower.

[image]
[image]
(seem all three perform the same in chrom)

**Long text** (12 time longer then normal)
https://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-includes-vs-test-2019-long-text-str/ 
**resume:**  All the three perform the same. (chrome and firefox)
[image]

**very short string** 
https://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-includes-vs-test-2019-too-short-string/
**resume:** includes and indexOf perform the same and test slower.

[image]

Note: about the benchmark above. For the **very short string** version (jsperf) had an big error for chrome. Seeing by my eyes. around 60 sample was run for both indexOf and includes same way (repeated a lot of time). And test a little bit less and so slower.
don't be fooled with the wrong graph. It's clear wrong. Same test work ok for firefox, surely it's a bug.

Here the illustration: (the first image was the test on firefox)
[image]
waaaa. Suddenly indexOf became superman. But as i said i did the test, and looked at the number of samples it was around 60. Both indexOf and includes and they performed the same. A bug on **jspref**. Except for this one (maybe because of a memory restriction related problem) all the rest was consistent, it give more details. And you see how many simple happen in real time.

## Final resume

**indexOf vs includes**  => Same performance

**test** => can be slower for short strings or text. And the same for long texts. And it make sense for the overhead that the regex engine add. In chrome it seemed it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: :thumbs-up: for the efforts :)

Answer (score 19):

Your comparison may not be entirely fair. `indexOf` is used with plain strings and is therefore very fast; `match` takes a regular expression - of course it may be slower in comparison, but if you want to do a regex match, you won't get far with `indexOf`. On the other hand, regular expression engines can be optimized, and have been improving in performance in the last years.

In your case, where you're looking for a verbatim string, `indexOf` should be sufficient. There is still one application for regexes, though: If you need to match *entire* words and want to avoid matching substrings, then regular expressions give you "word boundary anchors". For example:

```
indexOf('bar')
```

will find `bar` three times in `bar, fubar, barmy`, whereas

```
match(/\bbar\b/)
```

will only match `bar` when it is not part of a longer word.

As you can see in the comments, some comparisons have been done that show that a regex may be faster than `indexOf` - if it's performance-critical, you may need to profile your code.

Comment: I thought it a fair question, coming from a Perl background, where an equivalent regex is faster than `indexOf`.

Comment: It's no apples with oranges comparison as a trivial regex can be optimized to be as fast as `indexOf`. I've just run https://jsperf.com/substring-test and it claims that "regex case insensitive" is the fastest and 30% faster than "indexOf", which I refuse to believe.

Comment: While indexOf would find any of those strings, it will only find the first 'bar' in the string.

Answer (score 11):

If you're trying to search for substring occurrences **case-insensitively** then `match` seems to be faster than a combination of `indexOf` and `toLowerCase()`

Check here - http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof/152

Comment: Can confirm, here's another (working) benchmark: http://jsben.ch/Jw5yT -- Notice, regex wins every time whether pre-compiled or not, even faster than case sensitive index of according to this.

Answer (score 6):

You ask whether `str.indexOf('target')` or `str.match(/target/)` should be preferred. As other posters have suggested, the use cases and return types of these methods are different. The first asks "where in `str` can I first find `'target'`?" The second asks "does `str` match the regex and, if so, what are all of the matches for any associated capture groups?"

The issue is that neither one technically is designed to ask the simpler question "does the string contain the substring?" There is something that is explicitly designed to do so:

```
var doesStringContainTarget = /target/.test(str);
```

There are several advantages to using `regex.test(string)`:

1. It returns a boolean, which is what you care about
2. It is more performant than `str.match(/target/)` (and rivals `str.indexOf('target')`)
3. If for some reason, `str` is `undefined` or `null`, you'll get `false` (the desired result) instead of throwing a `TypeError`

Answer (score 5):

Using `indexOf` should, in theory, be faster than a regex when you're just searching for some plain text, but you should do some comparative benchmarks yourself if you're concerned about performance.

If you prefer `match` and it's fast enough for your needs then go for it.

For what it's worth, I agree with your colleagues on this: I'd use `indexOf` when searching for a plain string, and use `match` etc only when I need the extra functionality provided by regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Performance wise `indexOf` will at the very least be slightly faster than `match`. It all comes down to the specific implementation. When deciding which to use ask yourself the following question:

> Will an integer index suffice or do I
>   need the functionality of a RegExp
>   match result?

Answer (score 3):

### The return values are different

Aside from the performance implications, which are addressed by other answers, it is important to note that the return values for each method are different; so the methods cannot merely be substituted without also changing your logic.

**Return value of [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf): `integer`**

> The index within the calling `String` object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at `fromIndex`.
> *Returns `-1` if the value is not found.*

**Return value of [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match): `array`**

> An Array containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results.
> *Returns `null` if there were no matches*.

Because `.indexOf` returns `0` if the calling string *begins* with the specified value, a simple truthy test will fail.

**For example:**

*Given this class…*

```
class='DisablesGuiClass-2345-2d73-83hf-8293 redBorder'
```

*…the return values for each would differ:*

```
//  returns `0`, evaluates to `false`
if (string.indexOf('DisablesGuiClass-')) {
    … // this block is skipped.
}
```

*vs.*

```
//  returns `["DisablesGuiClass-"]`, evaluates to `true`
if (string.match(/DisablesGuiClass-/)) { 
    … // this block is run.
}
```

The correct way to run a truthy test with the return from `.indexOf` is to test against `-1`:

```
if (string.indexOf('DisablesGuiClass-') !== -1) {
//  ^returns `0`                        ^evaluates to `true`
    … // this block is run.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

remember Internet Explorer 8 doesnt understand `indexOf`.
But if nobody of your users uses ie8 (google analytics would tell you) than omit this answer.
possible solution to fix ie8:
[How to fix Array indexOf() in JavaScript for Internet Explorer browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers)

Comment: The question is about string search not array search.