# What is the easiest way to check if string contains any image tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have text:

```
"testestestestt testestestes <img src='image.jpg'>"
```

I want to write function which check if in string is `img` tag and return `true`

Comment: Easiest is regex, but it won't be very robust.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

using regex:

```
"testestestestt testestestes <img src='image.jpg'>".match(/<img/)
```

Comment: how to check if string contains img tags with text

Comment: @PrajapatiJigar you mean alt attribute or text inside image?

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "testestestestt testestestes <img src='image.jpg'>";
var hasImg = !!$('<div />').html(str).find('img').length
```

Comment: This will try to load the image when you add it to the div.

Comment: Although this will try to load the image when added to the div, it's the only answer that actually checks for the existence of an img element rather than just a string "img" or a variation of that.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, regular expressions are not recommend for parsing HTML, however, depending on the way you are using this, you may want to be assured that the `img` tag(s) have a corresponding ending tag.  This is a slightly more robust regular expression for that:

```
if("<img>TestString</img>".match(/<img[^<]*>[\w\d]*<\/img>|<img[^\/]*\/>/i))
{
  alert('matched');
}
else
  alert('nope');
```

Matched Test Cases:

```
- blahsdkfajsldkfj<img blah src=\"\">iImmage123dfasdfsa</img>
- blahsdkfajsldkfj<img>iImmage123dfasdfsa</img>asdfas
- <img src=\"\"></img>
- <img></img>
- <img />
```

Unmatched Test Cases:

```
- <img (other regex would match this)
- <img>
```

Once you match it you can easily process it with an XML or HTML parser are then check if it has the `src` attribute etc.

Comment: Hmm this gives me always null for this kind of img tags: ``testestestestestes <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0kZ5U.png" />``

Comment: @regedarek Make sure you don't have tags like this `<img src=".." /></img>` because if you do this `<img />` there's no need for a closing tag `</img>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, given answers are fast, but they may face some special cases which mispredict `img tags` e.g. `I posted my <picture> in <imgur>`

```js
`I posted my <picture> in <imgur>`.match(/<img/)
// ["<img", index: 25, ...]
```

also, there is a faster version of '<img' keyword search in a strings duo to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296314/10321531) in modern browsers.

```js
"testestestestt <img src='image.jpg'>".indexOf('<img') > -1
```

But the most reliable method is either you use a full `img tag` regex-matcher or let the browsers do things they've already done.

```js
const hasImage = htmlString => {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = htmlString

  return Boolean(div.querySelector('img'));
}

// tests
hasImage("testestestestt <img src='image.jpg'/>")
// true
hasImage("testestestestt <img src='image.jpg/>")
// false
hasImage("I posted my <picture> in <imgur>")
// false
```

`hasImage` function is highly inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/494348/10321531)