# Can I make tell some Javascript code to NOT run, if given text appears in the URL?

Tags: javascript

(I'm using Greasekit, so I'm working in Javascript)

## Can Javascript detect the URL of the currently loaded page?

I have some lines of code but I want to NOT run if `VeryHeavy` appears in the current URL.

Is this even possible, programmatically?

## Example

An example of the current URL would be:

`https://www.example.co.uk/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&page=35&tab=UK_VeryHeavy`

= I want the script to **not** run

When the URL is

`https://www.example.co.uk/wine/newsletter?ie=UTF8&page=35`

= I want the rest of the code to run. (In other words, do nothing)

Comment: `if (!function_to_find_text_in_url('VeryHeavy')) { ... code goes here ... }`?

Comment: Why the huuge fonts ? Accessibility ??

Comment: @techfoobar, That's just how the wikitext-generated headers are styled.

Comment: yes, it's for accessibility. ( I write in Markdown - i.e. i just place a # in front of the heading)

Comment: Ah.. Ok, never used that (just a regular bold n italics guy me!).. But imo those headings are way oversized to get the point across. :-)

Comment: @BrianDHall -1 for the w3schools reference :|

Comment: @DominicGoulet Normally I'd agree, but I couldnlt get the MozDev site to load. But now it works, so I'll edit so as to be more culturally appropriate :)

Comment: You're looking for the Location Object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (!(/VeryHeavy/.test(window.location.search))) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do I replace `/string/` with `VeryHeavy`? (please forgive my lack of knowledge!)

Comment: @ethagnawl Not a terribly big deal, but RegExps are way heavier on code than just using `.indexOf() == -1`. Probably won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href.contains("VeryHeavy")`

Just put that inside of an if statement.

**Example**

```
if (window.location.href.contains("VeryHeavy")) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Support for `contains` is very limited.

Comment: There is no `String.prototype.contains` method in JavaScript.  EDIT: This *only* exists in Firefox 19+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

Comment: @RocketHazmat it is implemented in JavaScript 1.8.6

Comment: @epascarello: I just looked it up, only Firefox currently supports it.  http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#String.prototype.contains

Comment: @RocketHazmat hence my first comment. ;)

Comment: @epascarello: Fair enough :)

Comment: Thanks, just tried it in Greasekit but it doesn't seem to work. :( I used ` document.write('helloooo')` to test and it didn't do anything (despite the loaded URL containing `VeryHeavy`

Answer (score 0):

The [Javascript Window Location Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) contains the information you seek.

> href  =   the entire URL: http://www.example.com:8080/search?q=devmo#test

Example:

```
var url = window.location.href;
alert( url );
```

You may then use Regex or the indexOf() method to test if the URL string contains something you would like. If you are doing a case-insensitive test it's probably best to use regex, as noted in ethagnawl's answer, as per this thread: [fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can.

Get the page URL in JavaScript with `document.URL`.