# Find a string in a string

Tags: javascript

How would I write an if statement that alerts when the var MyString is not in the var URL?

```
  var URL = "http://test.mysite.com/about/";
  var MyString = "mysite.com";
```

Comment: Compare the `indexOf` the word to `-1`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5296268/684368

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (URL.indexOf(MyString) === -1) {
    alert('Not found!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(URL.indexOf(MyString) == -1) alert("Not found");
```

Comment: I have two notes: 1) treating string literal as regular expression is not the same as checking if string is found withing a string (see especially special characters in pattern string), 2) the comparisons you are using are _evil_ (see more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/548696). Downvoting because of these two reasons.

Comment: @Tadeck Your second point is a personal style preference (even though it's same as mine).

Comment: @Tadeck - You are right I should probably remove the regex one.