# Searching if my string contain particular substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I want to check if my string contain particular substring.

1.What function should i use to perform this in javascript or jquery or using regex

for example

```
var a = "i am string";
var b = "i am webpage";

if(var_a_has_string)
{
 alert("it is string")
}

if(var_b_has_webpage)
{
alert("it is webpage")
}
```

sorry for repetition being a beginner i found some similar question but did not get the given answers here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038105/checking-if-a-string-contains-a-certain-substring

[Fastest way to check a string contain another substring in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript)

2.which function to be used if i want to retrieve the particular substring from my string

like "webpage" string or "string" string

for example

```
var a = "i am string";
var b = "i am webpage";

if(var_a_has_string)
{
 var c = get_string_from_a(a)
}

if(var_b_has_webpage)
{
 var d = get_webpage_from_b(b)
}
```

Comment: What didn't you understand in the answers to those questions?

Comment: 1 question/topic please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method like String.contains() in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript)

Comment: sorry i just edited my question i needed to get the substring and store in another variable @RohitJain

Comment: If you need the substring you're checking for why do you need a function to get it?  You already know what it is...

Comment: @bluetoft :hmmm i get ur point i can just check if it has that "str" string and if it has it using index of and if it has than i can assign the substring to my variable !!!! now when u r saying it this question feels really stupid !! thanks for the insight in it

Comment: hey pls dont downvote the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the other answers.. string.indexOf is what you're looking for.  It tells you the location of the substring within the string you're checking.  -1 for not found.

```
var stringToCheck = "i am stringpage";

var a = "i am string";
var b = "i am webpage";

if(stringToCheck.indexOf(a) > -1){
     alert("it is string")
}

if(stringToCheck.indexOf(b) > -1){
   alert("it is webpage")
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AEGef/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript function "indexOf"

It returns an integer, and -1 if the string hasn't been found.

```
 if (yourString.indexOf("stringToCheck") >= 0){
     //Insert some logic here
 }
```

Comment: Thanks!! can u check my edited question and ans it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, indexOf is what you need.

The MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

[To check if string contains another substring](http://code.askmein.com/how-to-check-if-string-contains-another-substring/) using Javascript use the below code

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to Javascript Coding.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");

//Returns 13

var s = "foo";
console.log(s.indexOf("oo") > -1)

//returns true
```

The other way to do the same thing is using includes

```
var str = "Hello World, Welcome to Javascript Coding";
console.log(str.includes("Welcome to"));    // true
console.log(str.includes("Javascript")); // true
console.log(str.includes("To be", 1)); // false
```