# Find special words in big text

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, find

**I MAKE :** I want to find  special words from programming domain (HTML,JavaScript,Back-end...) in big text (1000+ words) and put all programming words that I find to the new array

**PROBLEM :** In my mind there is yet only one way to do this.

1. Write **VERY BIG** array with programming words
2. Write a cycle that will compare every word from BIG TEXT with words from BIG ARRAY (with programming words)

But I think there is some solution that greatly simplify the task.

Any idea how to make this **MORE** easier ?

I write on server JavaScript

**EDIT :** guys i know about indexOf and etc. thank you but i want to find

1. Very fast algorithm to do it
2. How can I avoid writing the programming words (500+)

**"SOLVED :"** I found [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) 
Example :

```
var tagsObject = {
  "Java":"JAVA",
  "J2EE":"J2EE"
}

var words = "Java is a big language ! ! "

  var words = content.split(/\b/); // make array
  words = _.uniq(words); // make array with uniq words
  console.log(  _.intersection(words,_.keys(tagsObject))); // Computes the list of values that are the intersection of all the arrays, return array
//_.keys(tagsObject) - return array with keys
```

Comment: JavaScript has hashtables (maybe they're called "dictionaries"?)  Just put all your programming words into a hashtable (as keys; the values you pair them with aren't important) and then loop through each word in the "big text", looking it up in your hashtable.

Comment: What do you want to do when you find the words? Count them? Just acknowledge that the text contains them? There's some information missing from your question.

Comment: You *can* avoid writing the programming words, or at least have the computer help decide what they should be, but that is a big topic, and could take more time to implement than just writing the words by hand. I suggest you restrict this question to just the first part, which still needs some extra details from you to understand exactly what you are trying to do. Then if that goes well, and you understand the search part OK, come back to discovering the "programming words".

Comment: @NeilSlater I understand first part , but what for second ? Should i make new question ?

Comment: @nlpkr: Yes I suggest asking a second question. You will need to make clear what data you have in order to build the word list, and show what you have researched/tried. Any short code or data examples that clarify what it is you are looking for would help make it a better question. Also, if you now understand the first part thanks to the comments and answers given, it is normal practice on Stack Overflow to accept (tick) the answer that helped you.

Comment: @NeilSlater did this [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404445/make-object-with-programming-terms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. Actually what I like to recommend you is using a JS function named indexOf against your array. 
By this way, you would at least remove one of your loops. If the return value of the above JS func is -1 then the specific character is not found.

```
Var sourceArray=[a,b,c,d,e];

Var toBeFoundValues=[a,x,z,d];

For(var i=0;i<toBeFoundValues.length;I++)

If(sourceArray.indexOf(toBeFoundValues[I])!=-1)

// logic here
```

I hope the above code could help you.
Sorry if the code does not look pretty as am answering via my smart phone!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some [fast string searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) which come to mind, especially **Rabin-Karp**.

An implementation can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/antivanov/1120948), where you could also compare run times between the different functions:

```
function simpleSearch(text, str) {
   ...

function searchRabinKarp(text, str) {
   ...
```

The performance of standard methods (`regex` and `indexOf`) have been compared already in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score -3):

You could try using a regular expression. This one searches to see if `HTML`, `JavaScript`, or `Back-end` are in the string

```
var passingWords = "HTML,blah,otherWordsHere,JavaScript,Back-end";
var failingWords = "blah, otherWordsHere, h.tml, H.TML";
var re = new RegExp('(HTML)|(JavaScript)|(Back-end)');
console.log(re.test(passingWords));
console.log(re.test(failingWords));
```

It will return `true` if any of the words given in the `new` declaration are in the string given and `false` if they are not.

In your case you would probably want to test each word individually or write a different regular expression that allows for any combination of the words with any characters between each defined word.

This will only tell you if the word is in there or not, not where it is or any other information.

[JavaScript RegExp reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: This is a poor answer. You could improve it by showing _how_ you could use a regular expression.

Comment: @Andy Edited to include an example and more explanation