# Javascript if else with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to determine if an image source contains a string when I click on the image. The images have the class .swap-color. I have the variable $current_swatch set to the image src attribute, and it tests successfully. My code is below. No matter what image I click on, I get the alert "Contains TB", even if TB isn't in the image src. What am I doing wrong?

```
<img src="/images/Swatch-TB.jpg" class="swap-color"/>

$("document").ready(function () {
    $('.swap-color').click(function () {
        //get the image src
        var $current_swatch = $(this).attr('src');
        //check if TB is in the src
        if ($('$current_swatch:contains("TB")').length > 0 ) {
            alert ('Contains TB');
        } else {
            alert ('Does not contain TB');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside strings in Javascript, you should use concatenation.

Comment: And `:contains` isn't for searching strings, it's for searching DOM elements.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly reasonable, well-constructed question?

Comment: Some people downvote any question that indicates the poster is clueless and hasn't done any debugging on their own. Like use the JS console to see what `$('$current_swatch:contains("TB")')` returns.

Comment: @Barmar - Well, it's nice to bump into you again here on SO, and thank you for all your hard work! Good comments, good editing.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're using the [jQuery's `contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) method which checks if a selector contains a value. The problem is, `$current_swatch` is actually a string, since `$(this).attr('src')` will give `"/images/Swatch-TB.jpg"`.

Instead what you want is the [vanilla JS `includes`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
if ($current_swatch.includes('TB')) {
  ...
```

Comment: Isn't includes for arrays? Not strings per-se?

Comment: @cale_b not at all. Array and String both have `includes` and `indexOf` as part of their prototypes. Look at the doc I linked to - it's for String. I would argue in OP's case `includes` is more clear since OP isn't looking for the index, just if the value exists.

Comment: @cale_b to go further, if you really think about it, strings are implemented as arrays, so it makes sense that they would have many of the same methods.

Comment: Yes, agreed on strings == arrays.  And nice to learn about includes - always learning on SO.  Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Not really, since the array methods look for individual elements, while the string methods look for substrings.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst And there are many other differences, like you can modify an array, you can't modify a string.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't say all of the same - just some. But yeah, very big differences of course. Interestingly, on Chrome at least, [`indexOf` performs significantly better on large haystacks, while both methods seem equivalent on small haystacks](http://jsperf.com/string-indexof-includes)

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Other `.length` and `[index]`, I can't think of many similarities.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst They have some other methods with the same names, but they behave differently.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I'm looking at the (V8) source now. Interestingly enough, [`includes` actually just calls `indexOf`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/js/string.js#780), which makes sense.

Comment: Of course, it's just a convenience function to handle a common idiom. No need to repeat code.

Answer (score 4):

There's enough feedback that I'm going to go out on a limb and post an **answer**, even though the key to your question could be done in a comment.

The way to check for the contents is to use the JS native [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), rather than the jQuery selector method in your code.

Here's some commented revisions to your code:

```
// Streamlined, conflict-safe document ready
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.swap-color').click(function() {
        //get the image src
        var $current_swatch = $(this).attr('src');
        //check if TB is in the src
        // Use JS native "indexOf" rather than jQuery 
        if ($current_swatch.indexOf('TB') > -1 ) {
            alert ('Contains TB');
        } else {
            alert ('Does not contain TB');
        }
    });
});
```

For more information on different ways to check for a substring, check out this answer: [Fastest way to check a string contain another substring in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript)