# What solution performs faster for searching substring in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, performance

I need to check if some string contains another string (substring) so
can someone tell me which one of this perform faster:

```
someString.includes(thisSubstring) or 
someString.indexOf(thisSubstring) !== -1
```

It depends from the browser? Are there any faster solutions?

Comment: measure it yourself.

Comment: Go to https://jsfiddle.net/, create a string, create a loop with a timer that iterates n times and performs n `includes` checks. Then another loop with a timer that performs n `indexof` checks. Then come back here, post the fiddle along with your answer of which one is faster.

Comment: Use the search. It is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` is faster, but you could have easily run these test yourself.

In the future you can use the pattern below to measure execution time:

```js
var str1 = "nananananaananana Catman!";
var str2 = "Catman!";
var max = 10000000;
var t = new Date();
for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  str1.indexOf(str2) >= 0;
}
console.log("indexOf",new Date() - t);
t = new Date();
for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  str1.includes(str2);
}
console.log("includes",new Date() - t);
t = new Date();
for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  str1.indexOf(str2) >= 0;
}
console.log("indexOf",new Date() - t);
t = new Date();
for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  str1.includes(str2);
}
console.log("includes",new Date() - t);
```

Comment: @Prusse If this had been a question of higher complexity, i probably would, but with something this simple i wanted to give OP the tools to log however she/he pleases (private unittest, quick performance tests, etc.) by showcasing the simplest performance test pattern.