# Optimizing search of array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects that is a length of 5,866 like formatted like this `{label: "Luke Skywalker", value: "556534"}`
and I am searching the objects and filtering by their label like so

```
  onChange = (e) => {
        e.persist()
         this.setState({filter:e.target.value, filtered_array: 
            this.state.raw_user_list.filter(user =>
              user.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) > -1)})
    }

...
     <form style={{paddingBottom:'10px'}}>
              Filter: <input name="filter" value={this.state.filter} onChange={this.onChange} type="text" style={{
                border: '1px solid #cccccc',
              }}/>
            </form>
```

`this.state.filter` is the value that is being types in to filter.
Before I was working with less than 1,000 entries initially and now with the `user_list` being 5,866 causes performance issues with the way I am filtering. I want to filter the data real-time when the user types.

Comment: Don't perform `e.target.value.toLowerCase()` for each iteration. Store it in a scoped variable that you reference from the iteration function. That's one easy fix that should give you immediate results.

Comment: Aside from externalizing the lowerCase (you're repeating it each loop), you may think about using some external libraries, if allowed. Fuse.js seems to be your friend in that case specifically: https://github.com/krisk/Fuse

Comment: Issue is more likely related to how you are using this. 5900 elements is not a lot

Comment: Okay let me restructure it based off the comments. I'll look into Fuse.js after. I want to avoid using another library.

Comment: Some throttling in the `onChange` would  help if it is related to continuous typing

Comment: also, if the current filter contains the previous filter, then the current result is a subset of `filtered_array` and you don't have to filter the entire `raw_user_list` again.

Comment: thinking on these comments of not calling `e.target.value.toLowerCase()` the reason I am doing this is so the filter is real-time. So I think this route wouldn't work

Comment: @user10204157 Ok, but you don't have to compute `e.target.value.toLowerCase()` 5866 times (per keypress).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways to optimize your searching function :

Using `includes` instead of `indexOf`, wich does not return an index, but only true/false

```
this.state.raw_user_list.filter(user => user.label.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()))
```

According to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296314/6919895), a Regex would be a lot faster (for Chrome in particular) :

```
this.state.raw_user_list.filter(user => user.label.match(new RegExp(e.target.value, 'i')))
```

Using the 'i' option in your Regex means that it is case insensitive

---

**UPDATE**

According to [these tests](https://jsperf.com/substring-test), your function can be even faster than the previous one with a cached Regex :

```
const rValue = new RegExp(e.target.value, 'i')
this.state.raw_user_list.filter(user => rValue.test(user.label))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Trie data structure (https://github.com/Draluy/MCsolver/blob/master/src/services/DictService.js)

Basically that will allow you to find words a lot quickier. I used it in a project to store all the words of the dictionnary and searches are tipically under a millisecond.

You can find my implementation here:
https://github.com/Draluy/MCsolver/blob/master/src/services/DictService.js