# How do I search for a part of a string from a specific character?

Tags: javascript, string

I've this:

```
"example: myresult"
```

And I need a method that looks for this from ": "

```
"myresult"
```

I tried with String.search()

Comment: How reliable is the format of the string? If you know it's always going to have a colon and single white space separating them, then you can just use `.split`. e.g. `"example: myresult".split(': ')[1]` will give you "myresult"

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting?

Comment: Split method works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
function getSecondPart(str) {
    return str.split(':')[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `string.includes(searchString, position)`, that have a second param of position to start the search.

> [position Optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#parameters)
> The position within the string at which to begin searching for searchString. (Defaults to 0.)

```js
const str = "example: myresult";
const startIndex = str.indexOf(': ');
console.log(str.includes('example')); // true
console.log(str.includes('example', startIndex)); // false
console.log(str.includes('myresult', startIndex)); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort you have also the regular expression route to extract the value following semicolons preceded by a label:

```js
const subject = "example: myresult";
const re = /^.+?\: (.+)$/im;
const match = re.exec(subject);
let result = "";
if (match !== null) {
    result = match[1];  
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: "last resort" indeed 

Comment: it was an unfortunate way to introduce my answer as just the nth option among many.. and the less appropriate indeed. On the other hand it scales better in case you mean to make changes to the parsing rules at any time.. but that's just an added consideration

Comment: well it's hard to tell if it will scale better, dynamic regex over dynamic string known to be less efficient https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296314/1761692

Comment: by scaling I meant how much effort is required to change the logic in case the syntax changes. The regex is easy to change if your parsing rules get different. Any other strategy like using split or tricks to get the semicolon position, will require to reconsider the whole block. Of course, performance wise, the regex is the less efficient way to deal with that problem... that's why I said _the less appropriate (option)_. Anyway I didn't mean to win the competition just cite an added option. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ": " is always consistent this should work for you:

```js
var myresult = "example: myresult";
console.log(myresult.split(': ')[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
'string'.includes(':')
```

you can check if the symbol or letter is in the word by includes in the words

Comment: this only answer part of the question