# is String.includes faster than String.search?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

`word.includes(str)` returns a `boolean` indicating whether or not `str` is included in `word`
 `word.search(str)` returns a `number` representing the position of the first `str` found in `word`, `-1` if it does not exist.

At first, I wondered why JavaScript provides both, however it's possible to create only one method that works for both cases, returns position else returns `undefined`, but since both exist, so it should be for a reason, maybe `String.includes` is faster, or maybe, it's just to make things clearer.

It looks like `String.includes` should be faster as it only checks if `str` exists rather than trying to find its position, however, **my simple thought:** to check if `str` exists in `word` the algorithm should loop through the `word` characters anyway (if there is something I'm missing let me know) and once `str` is found, it can easily retrieve its position, so `String.includes` couldn't be faster.

I want to know the real difference between them and why both exist. thank you!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303099) answer your question? It includes a comparison of numerous methods to search a string. (`string.search` is also intended to be used with regular expressions)

Comment: it does not sorry

Comment: "[I]t's possible to create only one method that works for both cases, returns position else returns undefined" No; a function returns undefined if a value was not returned ([MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)) and therefore using `undefined` as a return value is unconventional.

Comment: "*it's possible to create only one method that works for both cases*" - sure that's possible, but it would be awkward to use. You'd have to write `if (word.something(str) != undefined)` all the time. Just as weird as, but even longer than, the existing `if (word.indexOf(str) > -1)` or  `if (word.search(regex) > -1)`. That's why `if (word.includes(str))` was created - for convenience and clarity. It has more to do with the speed of the developer writing, reading and understanding the code, than with the speed of the string search algorithm.

Comment: `if (word.something(str))` would react the same to it returning undefined (str not found) and it returning 0 (str at start of word).  That's why you'd need the explicit `!= undefined` check.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: @AhmedSbai No you don't write `array.find(…)`, unless you actually want to get the value back (and `undefined` if not found). If you just want to know whether the value exists, you use `array.some(…)` which appropriately returns a boolean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The big difference between the two is that `search()` takes a regex - much more flexible and (probably) slower than the match in `includes()` that can be done quickly with something like [boyer-moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm)

The companion to `includes()` is `indexOf()` which is probably very comparable algorithmically. With that pair, it could make sense to build includes() as a bool-returning wrapper around indexOf().

Comment: Note that `.search()` also accepts [anything with a `@@search` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

Comment: `includes()` and `indexOf()` speeds are fairly similar. it just use cases that are different.

Answer (score 2):

[`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is basically a convenience method which just uses [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). They both accept a string argument and an optional (start) position argument. They try to find a matching substring value inside the string.

[`String.prototype.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) is then better compared to [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) because they both return the index of the matched content.
`.search()` works differently because it performs a regex search, while `.indexOf()` just tries to find the exact substring.

Thus it's easy to conclude that `.search()` must always be slower than `.indexOf()`, and therefore slower than `.contains()`, because checking if a substring is equal to a value is slower than checking if a substring matches a regex rule.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking them?

Comment: @code Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript/54303099#54303099