# find a specific string pattern in an array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find the solution.
I am trying to find a specific string pattern in an array.
I want to find all values in data that contain 'underscore r underscore'. I then want to create a new array that contains only those keys and values.

```
var data = ["something", "bar_r_something"];
var resultArray = new Array();    
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var bar = /_r_/;
    if ($.inArray(bar, data[i].length) > 0)
    {
       console.log("found _r_");
       resultArray.push(data[i]);
    }
};
```

I just can't seem to get that $.inArray to work, it seems to always kick out -1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - search for a string inside an array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424488/javascript-search-for-a-string-inside-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var data = ["something", "bar_r_something"];
var resultArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var bar = /_r_/;
    if (bar.test(data[i])) {
        alert("found _r_");
        resultArray.push(data[i]);
    }
};

console.log(resultArray);
```

Here you go, it doesn't use `$.inArray`, but Regex instead, hope that's cool!

EDIT

If you wanted to go a bit more fancy, you can use JavaScript's filter method like so:

```
var data = ["something", "bar_r_something"];
var resultArray = data.filter(function(d){
    return /_r_/.test(d);
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [$.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/). Also [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray) does not test the values against a regex, it tests for equality.

```
var regex = /_r_/
var resultArray  = $.grep(data, function(item){
    return regex.test(item)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ewRU2/)