# How to find a value into an Array of Obects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array of Objects in Javascript:

```
function focal( name, data )
{
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
}

count = 0;

arrayFocal = [];
arrayFocal[count] = new focal( "Name", "12/08/2014" );
count++;
```

Now I want to find into `arrayFocal` by name
**NOTE**: IE 8

Comment: I tried inArray, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424488/javascript-search-for-a-string-inside-an-array-of-strings , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116474/how-to-find-if-an-array-contains-a-specific-string-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: `var` is a lovely little thing when you use it ;) And adding to array should be done using `push` would avoid having that count variable. And then the solution is just to use `filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution:

As @Mritunjay suggested:

You can use `filter`

```
arrayFocal.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.name=='Name';
});
```

But I am using IE 8, and it does not support `filter`
So we provide an implementation for the filter() method, as @Jason M. Batchelor suggested:
http://www.devcurry.com/2011/02/filter-array-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 7):

You can use `filter`

```
arrayFocal.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.name=='Name';
});
```

It will return an array of objects which `name` matched. If you want just first one you can `[0]` for that.

Comment: Note, however, that this does not work in IE prior to IE 9. If you want older browser support, you'll need to come up with a different solution, or use a third-party library such as underscore.js.

Comment: See this page for an approach to the DIY solution: http://www.devcurry.com/2011/02/filter-array-using-javascript.html
You'd then use filter the way @Mritunjay described, above, instead of the `function isEven...` function that they use in that example.

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore

```
_.findWhere(arrayFocal, {name: name})
```

Comment: I tried to use `alert( _.findWhere(arrayFocal, {name: nomeFocal}) );` but it return an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Comment: but the name i am looking for is in a var

Comment: Yes, presumably the var named `nameFocal`