# Simple search without database

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, search

I know there's a way to do it but I can't find it! 
In my very early html writing days (2007) I found a simple code for searching by specified search words.
Meaning- the user inputs a word into the `search box`, and the site searches for it in an `array` within it. It could even find results for letters and word fragments. 
I can't find something like that now...

Is the a way to specify an `array` and use JS or JQuery to search it even if the search word isn't exact? similar to MySQL's `LIKE`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424488/javascript-search-for-a-string-inside-an-array-of-strings

Answer (score 0):

If you have the input, and the full list of searchable value, you could compute the Levenshtein distance to do a "sort-of" LIKE ; libs like https://github.com/gf3/Levenshtein could help...

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/