# if an array contains a specific value, then return the full 'content' of the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, search

The idea is this..

```
var myArray = ['Apple juice','Banana Milkshake','Some Treat'];
function search(search_term){
if(myArray.indexOf(search_term) != -1){
     return ..... //this is what i want to do.
};

// code is run as.
search("Apple");
```

My thought is when i call the `search()` function and it finds a value, it should return the full length or the full value of the matched term
so if i do `search("Apple");` it should return 'Apple Juice'
but i don't know any way to do this so can anyone help me find a way to do this?

Comment: check this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424488/javascript-search-for-a-string-inside-an-array-of-strings

Comment: @jQuery It's a duplicate of that. Voting to close.

Comment: @Scimonster want to close this question as duplicate?

Comment: @jQuery I voted to close, as did one other person, but it needs 3 more votes (or a gold badge holder).

Comment: the easy way: `['Apple juice','Banana Milkshake','Some Treat'].filter(/./.test, /Apple/);`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
for (var i in myArray)
    if (myArray[i].indexOf(search_term) != -1)
        return myArray[i];
```

Or if you want to return all matches in an array:

```
myArray.filter(function(item) {
    return item.indexOf(search_term) != -1;
});
```

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Read the question again.

Comment: That's more like it.

Comment: thanks! im just a beginner at this so its hard but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that ?

```
   var myArray = ['Apple juice','Banana Milkshake','Some Treat', 'Here'];

    function search(search_term){
        for(var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

            if(myArray[i].indexOf(search_term) !== -1) {
                return myArray[i];
            }
        }

        return false;
    };

    // code is run as.
    alert(search("Here"));
```