# Javascript: Regex vs IndexOf when scanning for a list of keywords

Tags: javascript, regex, indexof

I see that indexOf is faster when you're scanning against one word according to the solution here [JavaScript: indexOf vs. Match when Searching Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757438/javascript-indexof-vs-match-when-searching-strings)

However, what if you have a list of say 5 keywords and you want to count the occurrence of each (assuming each word appears only once in the string of large text).

Would the below be faster?

```
var list1 = ['word1', 'word2','word3','word4','word5'];
for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
     if (exampleLargeText.indexOf(list1[i]) > -1){
    keywordCounter++;
    }
}
```

vs....

```
var keywordRegex =  'word1|word2|word3|word4|word5'];  
var keywordCounter = exampleLargeText.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp(SUBMIT_ELEMENT_REGEX , "ig")) || []).length
```

Is indexOf() still faster despite the fact that you're scanning exampleLargeText 5 times here?

Comment: Test it. That's the only way to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression like `/aaa|bbb|ccc/` will never be more efficient than a simpler (yet still similar, 3 characters) expression like `/abc/`. This is because regex engines match left to right. The easiest matches would be 'aaa' for the first and 'abc' for the second...each of these take 3 steps. Now, imagine, you try to match 'aabbccx' to both expressions. The first expression would take a total of 33 steps and the second would take 5 steps, this is because each alternation (denoted by `|`) forces the regex engine to start over. Play around with that on a tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com).

However, if you were able to make your regular expression *more* optimized than just checking each word separately, there is a *chance* it could beat `.indexOf()`. For instance, if your expression is truly `/word1|word2|word3|word4|word5/`, it could be rewritten as `/word[1-5]/`. This is way more efficient than looking for each word separately because now the expression is defined in a simple pattern. Who knows, though, `.indexOf()` still may be faster depending on the overhead.

That's when benchmarking comes into play -- use [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/)!