# Javascript Regex - match int after string in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to capture the counts associated with the keywords in the string txt.  All the keywords are loaded into an array ahead of time.

This code is in jquery/javascript.  I cannot hard code string keywords so that is why they are stored in an array.  Please assist me in finding what goes in place of "Reg Expression" before and/or after the keyword variable within the loop.

The html br can be used to end that regexmatch in that iteration of the loop.

Trying to end up with keywordCount = "2, 5, 11"

```
//String I need to search through
var txt = "Edit Req'd2<br>Errors5<br>Pndg App11<br>";

//array of keywords I can use to find associated counts to keywords
var keyword = ["Edit Req'd", "Errors", "Pndg App"];

//empty string declared before loop
var keywordCount = '';

for (i = 0; i < keyword.length; i++) {

    // takes the comma off end of first entry in array
    // might not be needed or another method might be better?
    keyword[i] = $.trim(keyword[i]);

    //regex expression generated using keyword and unknown expression 
    var regexmatch = RegExp("Reg Expression" + keyword + "Reg Expression")

    //use regex expression to generate string containing counts
    keywordCount += (txt.match(regexmatch)) + ",";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a number in a string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623221/how-to-find-a-number-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: Try: var regexmatch = RegExp(keyword[i] + "(\d+)"), then grap Group 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a digit/numeric range to match the number (`[0-9]`; this is pretty basic regex stuff), and use a group to match any of the keywords:

- Any number of digits: `[0-9]+`
- Any of your keywords: `(something|somethingelse|other)`

You can use capture-groups as well to have `match()` return them separately:

```
var keyword = ["Edit Req'd", "Errors", "Pndg App"];
var regexmatch = RegExp('(\b' + keyword.join('|') + ')([0-9]+)', 'g')
```

*(note that we use the word-boundary `\b` to make sure keyword is not part of a longer word, and the 'g' flag for global to signal we want multiple results)*

Now, `match()` will only match one result, and we want matches for every keyword, so we’ll use `exec()` instead:

```js
var txt = "Edit Req'd2<br>Errors5<br>Pndg App11<br>";
var keyword = ["Edit Req'd", "Errors", "Pndg App"];
var regex = RegExp('(\b' + keyword.join('|') + ')([0-9]+)', 'g')

var match = regex.exec( txt ); // ...find the first match
var numbers = [];

while ( match !== null ) {
  numbers.push( match[ 2 ]); // #0 of exec() its return-value is the result as a whole: "Edit Req'd2"
                             // #1 is the value of the first capture-group: "Edit Req'd"
                             // #2 is the value of the second capture-group: "2"

  match = regex.exec( txt ); // ...find the next match
}

console.log("the numbers are:", numbers);
```

Lastly, do note that regular expressions may look cool, they are [not always the fastest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4757501/3997374) (performance-wise). If performance matters a lot, you could use (for example) `indexOf()` instead.

---

*From your question it seems like you could brush up on your knowledge of regular expressions a little bit. There’s a ton of articles around (just search for* “regular expressions basics” *or* “regex 101”) – like this one: 
https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285*

Comment: JavaScript regex does not support look behind.

Comment: Thanks, tested with an online regex-tester and in devtools console, but evidently too lazy; not all browsers support them. Changed the answer to something without lookbehinds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example which may helps you in achieving your required output.

```js
//String I need to search through
var txt = "Edit Req'd2<br>Errors5<br>Pndg App11<br>";

//array of keywords I can use to find associated counts to keywords
var keyword = ["Edit Req'd", "Errors", "Pndg App"];

//empty string declared before loop
var keywordCount = '';
var i = 0;
var keywordCount = "";
var splittedValue = "";
while (i < keyword.length) {
    if (txt.indexOf(keyword[i]/i)) {
        splittedValue = txt.split(keyword[i]);
        if (keywordCount === "") {
            keywordCount = splittedValue[1].split("<br>")[0];
        } else {
            keywordCount += ", " + splittedValue[1].split("<br>")[0];
        }
    }
    i += 1;
}
console.log(keywordCount);
```